# Move table columns from one row into another

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am working with software that automatically generates a form after you select your options, so the code is automatically generated and I cannot directly edit it. The code it outputs for this form is in tables. I would like the Amount, the radio buttons and their labels to all appear in one line however?
Because I cannot edit the code directly, is there a way to do this w js? Possibly moving all of the columns into one row?
 Here is the link to a jsfiddle to the basic code it outputs: https://jsfiddle.net/jelane20/Lt36fq6f/1/

```
    <table class="form">
 <tbody id="panel">
  <tr>
   <td id="field">
    <label id="amount">Amount</label>
   </td>
   <td class="fieldsRight">
    <table id="options">
     <tbody>
      <tr>
       <td class="controlcell">
        <span class="top" item index="51" amount="25.00" >
         <input id="ad_51_6" type="radio">
          <label for="ad_51_6"> </label>
        </span>
       </td>
       <td class="fieldRight">
        <span>$25.00</span>
       </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
       <td class="controlcell">
        <span class="top" item index="52" amount="50.00">
         <input id="ad_52_6" type="radio">
          <label for="ad_52_6"> </label>
        </span>
       </td>
       <td class="fieldRight">
        <span>$50.00</span>
       </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
<tbody>
   </td>
  </tr>
 </tbody>
</table>
```

Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: Can you edit your fifflde to show what you want you output to look like? Do you just want the elements from the form to be on same line??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may add to your css the following rule:

```
#options tr {
    display: inline-table;
}
```

If you want to achieve the same result with jQuery you can write:

```
$('#options tr').css('display', 'inline-table');
```

Instead, if you need to move the sub table content to the upper table you can:

```
$('#options tr td').each(function(i, e) {
   $(this).appendTo('table.form tr:first');
});
```

The snippet (css solution):

```css
#options tr {
  display: inline-table;
}
```

```html
<table class="form">
    <tbody id="panel">
    <tr>
        <td id="field">
            <label id="amount">Amount</label>
        </td>
        <td class="fieldsRight">
            <table id="options">
                <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td class="controlcell">
                        <span class="top" item index="51" amount="25.00">
                            <input id="ad_51_6" type="radio">
                            <label for="ad_51_6"> </label>
                        </span>
                    </td>
                    <td class="fieldRight" >
                        <span>$25.00</span>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="controlcell">
                        <span class="top" item index="52" amount="50.00">
                            <input id="ad_52_6" type="radio">
                            <label for="ad_52_6"> </label>
                        </span>
                    </td>
                    <td class="fieldRight">
                        <span>$50.00</span>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
    <tbody>
    </td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

The snippet (jQuery solution):

```js
$('#options tr td').each(function(i, e) {
  $(this).appendTo('table.form tr:first');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table class="form">
    <tbody id="panel">
    <tr>
        <td id="field">
            <label id="amount">Amount</label>
        </td>
        <td class="fieldsRight">
            <table id="options">
                <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td class="controlcell">
                        <span class="top" item index="51" amount="25.00">
                            <input id="ad_51_6" type="radio">
                            <label for="ad_51_6"> </label>
                        </span>
                    </td>
                    <td class="fieldRight">
                        <span>$25.00</span>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="controlcell">
                        <span class="top" item index="52" amount="50.00">
                            <input id="ad_52_6" type="radio">
                            <label for="ad_52_6"> </label>
                        </span>
                    </td>
                    <td class="fieldRight">
                        <span>$50.00</span>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
    <tbody>
    </td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: You are my hero, so much simpler than how I was attempting to do this. Thank you so much!!